# Django AttributeError: calling form.is_valid() always results in Object has no attribute 'is_vaild'

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I've been searching for solutions for a whole day and I have almost gone through all the answers on Stackoverflow and still cannot solve my problem. So, I have to raise this question.

In models.py, I have:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Cap(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dest_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cap_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    text_part = models.FileField(upload_to='texts/%Y/%m/%d')

    time_to_live = models.IntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Then in forms.py, I have:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from latercap.models import Capsule

class CapForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cap
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then in views.py, I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from myapp.forms import CapForm

def upload(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CapForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_vaild():
            form.save()
            # Redirect to the upload page after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/myapp/upload/')
    else:
        form = CapForm() # An empty, unbound form

    message = "You can upload your message here!"
    context = {'message': message, 'form': form}

    # Render upload page with the documents and the form
    return render(request, 'myapp/upload.html', context)
```

Then in upload.html, I have:

```
<b>{{message}}</b>

<form action="{% url 'myapp:upload' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
    <p>Title: {{ form.title }}</p>
    <p>From: {{ form.user_id }}</p>
    <p>To: {{ form.dest_id }}</p>
    <p>No. {{ form.cap_id }}</p>
    <p>Open after: {{ form.time_to_live }}</p>
    <p>Publish date: {{ form.pub_date }}</p>
    <p>My message:</p>
    <p>
       {{ form.text_part }}
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
```

When I set correct values into the form and click "Upload" button, I ALWAYS get:

```
> AttributeError at /myapp/upload/ 'CapForm' object has no attribute
> 'is_vaild'
> Request Method:   POST Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/upload/
> Django Version:   1.6.5
> Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value:  'CapForm' object
> has no attribute 'is_vaild'
```

I have tried:

- `print form.errors`, but nothing was shown
- `print form.is_valid()` before the `if`, still gives the error
- delete the `text_part` and only pass `request.POST` to the `form`, still gives errors
- use `form(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)`, still errors
- `print form.is_multipart()` give me a `True` result
- submit an empty or correctly filled form all give the same error

What should I do to get this work? Many many thanks!

Comment: looks like you have a typo: is_vaild() not equal to is_valid()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
is_vaild != is_valid
```

Simple typo

Comment: Tricky typo. If it happened to me, I'd never find it.

Comment: ar.....I must be too tired today....should I get a new pair of glasses...

Comment: Hehe - On bad days, I've spent hours pouring through code only to find the cause is a simple typo - eg. a typo in the attribute of a Django model - "Why isn't this attribute being updated!?!?"